# How do I pass variable values onto a cart page for a promotion?

Tags: url, parameter-passing, e-commerce

I am new to Stack Overflow and am not a hardcore engineer so I preface this question with the request to please be nice. I am not even sure it is possible to do what I want.

I want to run a promotion from an email where the URL parameters will prepopulate the shopping cart with a product, quantity and coupon code.

I have tried passing form values with a ?varname=value and it does not work.

The example URL below is not my site, but I have a site similar. I would like to create a URL where I can populate the fields with a click.

example: http://www.jdusiwines.com/shop/cart.php?coupon=HOLIDAY

Ideally, I would like a URL that populates the cart with products and quantity to make it easier for customers to purchase from an email campaign. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

If this is not detailed enough, please let me know what else you need to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using sessions? Else hidden form fields could provide what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I will try a hidden form field. That may do the trick.